# formatting string with commas. looking into get indexes

Tags: python

```
str = '123,4,5'
str[0] = 1
```

wanted outcome: '123'

I have tried using the .split(',') with no success.
How do I get the wanted outcome?

Comment: How did you use `split` and how was it "no success"?

Comment: I guess you tried to use `.split` on the list? Use it on the string *in the list* instead.

Comment: `.split()` only works on strings, how are you calling it?

Comment: `lst[0].split(',')[0]`

Comment: @user145682 Why do you think that `lst[0] = 1` will give you the desired outcome?

Answer (score 2):

try the follwing:

```py
part_1 = ['123,4,5']
print(part_1)
part_2 = lst[0].split(',')
print(part_2)
part_2[0]
```

Comment: `2nd` as a variable name is going to throw a syntax error.

Comment: `str` is a python keyword better to use it the way I showed you. and you should try to understand it. also check Pika lè Sorcerer of the Whales answer. will give you more info to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
lst = ['123,4,5']
lst2 = lst[0].split(',')
```

will set `lst2` to `['123', '4', '5']`. You can now use `lst2[0]` to get the value `'123'`.

As was mentioned in the comments, you probably tried using .split on the list and not the string inside the list; using `lst.split` will not work. The code above uses `lst[0].split`, which operates on the string inside the list, not the list itself.

Note that if `lst`, prior to using `split`, has more than one string stored inside, the above solution will replace the original list with the split version of *only the first element*, meaning the list `['1,2', '3,4']` would be converted to `['1', '2']`. If you wish for that list to result in `['1', '2', '3', '4']`, you can loop through each element in the list, like so:

```
lst = ['123,4,5','6,7']
lst2 = []
for i in lst:
    for j in i.split(','):
        lst2.append(j)
```